# Video shows black screen after uploading with PaperClip AV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, video, paperclip

I am using PaperClip AV Transcoder, and when I upload a video all I see is a black image. I presume that video is not getting uploaded.

Do I also have to install a video player as well with it, or does that come with the PaperClip AV?

My model that has the video:

```
class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 has_attached_file :video, :styles => {
:medium => { :geometry => "640x480", :format => 'mp4' },
:thumb => { :geometry => "100x100#", :format => 'jpg', :time => 10 }
 }, :processors => [:transcoder]

validates_attachment_content_type :video, :content_type => ["video/mp4",     "video.mov", "video/mpeg","video/mpeg4", "image/jpg", "image/jpeg"]

end
```

My show view for the video:

```
<%= video_tag @pin.video.url %>

<p>
 <strong>Description:</strong>
 <%= @pin.description %>
</p>

<% if @pin.user == current_user %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_pin_path(@pin) %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', pins_path %>
```

I don't know what other code would help. I'd gladly write any other lines of code that might help.

A picture of what I am talking about:

[image]

This is a screenshot of my ffmpeg version from my command line:

[image]

Comment: I just want to check, I assume you've got some kind of Javascript function that's triggering the play event, right? If not, `video_tag` just spits out a native `video` tag without controls. So, nothing will happen (although I'd expect it to show the first frame). If you want controls for testing, you can try `video_tag @pin.video.url, :controls => true`

Comment: i added this and it did add the play button and volume. But still just a black screen even when I push the play button. I have a feeling that for some reason the video isnt uploading. Thank you for your advice, I was wondering how to add the play button

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `transcoder` as your processor. You need to install this [paperclip-av-transcoder](https://github.com/ruby-av/paperclip-av-transcoder) gem too. (If already not there, add the to your `Gemfile` and do: `bundle install`).

Also, you may need to [install ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) in your machine to get the processor to work locally.

After these steps, it should work for you.

Comment: I have the latest version of paperclip-av-transcoder installed and I believed I installed ffmpeg right

Comment: Try installing a video player then, and let us know!

Comment: Do you know of any free video players for ruby?

Comment: btw, which browser are you using to try the video? Check here what formats are supported by what browser: http://caniuse.com/#search=video

Comment: Im using chrome so I should be fine on that part

Comment: Just use the [`<video>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) for HTML5

Answer (score 0):

There are several steps to debug this.

---

Firstly, you need to **check if the video file has been saved**.

If the video file exists, it means your problem lies with *playback* (not *processing*). Thus you'll need to browse to `public/system/.....`

If you're on your dev machine, you can do this by simply browsing to `/public/system`, if you're using [Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-command) or another web server, you'll have to [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) into the [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) and `cd` to the directory:

**Heroku**

```
$ heroku run bash
$ cd public/system
$ ls
```

**SSH**

```
SSH into your system
cd /app_root/public/system
ls
```

You'll then be able to browse through the folders to get to the appropriate directory containing your videos...

[image]

--

If you have the video on your system, it means they've been processed.

If they're *not* on your system, you need to consult your `logs` (post them on here), and show us what the error might have been.

To *playback* your video, you'll be able to use the [HTML5 `<video>` tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) ([Rails `video_tag`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/video_tag)):

```
<%= video_tag @attachment.paperclip_object.url %>
```

This will show the video (if it's been transcoded into MP4 or another compatible file format), allowing the playback to occur.

---

**Cover**

Another issue you will have is the cover image.

It seems you've set this up properly; you can use it as follows:

```
<%= video_tag @attachment.paperclip_object.url, poster: @attachment.paperclip_object.thumb.url %>
```